# UNIX domain socket C++ server can not return data to client

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, boost-asio, socat

Here are the simple echo server I'm working on, the server will accept the request from client and return what client sends to it. The program works fine with `socat`, but will freeze when using my own client.

The problem that my old code has is that I use `read` instead of `read_some`. `read` will block the pipe until it reads certain number of bytes or get a broken pipe exception, whereas `read_some` will read a chunk at a time. The updated version uses `read_some` to read input stream and check if the last character the program read is `\0`, if it is `\0`, that means it reaches the end of command, so it will echo back. This works because I only pass string literals and there is no binary data in the pipe.

The code of the server is

```
using namespace std;

const char* epStr = "/tmp/socketDemo";

int main() {
  namespace local = boost::asio::local;

  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  ::unlink(epStr);

  local::stream_protocol::endpoint ep(epStr);
  local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor(io_service, ep);

  while(1) {
    local::stream_protocol::socket *socket = new local::stream_protocol::socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(*socket);

    char buf[2048] = {0};
    boost::system::error_code error;

    size_t len = 0;
      while(1) {
        len += socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf + len, 2048 - len));
        cout << "read " << len << endl;
        if (buf[len] == '\0') {
          break;
        }
      }

    cout << "read " << len << " bytes" << endl;
    cout << buf << endl;

    boost::asio::write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(buf, len), boost::asio::transfer_all());
  }
}
```

When testing the server with `socat` command, for example

```
echo "12345" | socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/socketDemo
```

it will return the desired result.

My client code is

```
const char* epStr = "/tmp/socketDemo";

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint ep(epStr);
  boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket socket(io_service);

  socket.connect(ep);

  boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(argv[1], strlen(argv[1])), boost::asio::transfer_all());

  char buf[1024] = {0};

  size_t len = 0;
    while(1) {
      len += socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf + len, 2048 - len));
      std::cout << "read " << len << std::endl;
      if (buf[len] == '\0') {
        break;
      }
    }

  std::cout << "read " << len << " bytes\n";

  std::cout << buf << std::endl;

  socket.close();
```

When execute the client, at first both have no output, after I killed the client, the server will output that it reads n bytes and get a broken pipe exception.

Can this be caused by the `read` function in the server? If so is there a way to let it know how much data it should read without sending the size of data chunk at the beginning of each message? I am also wondering why `socat` can work with this server without any problem? Thanks!

Comment: use `static` qualifier for `epStr `

Comment: @self, what does it have to do with the question?

Comment: I think you're looking for [read_some](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks, with `read_some` and @llya 's answer I have solved this.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am also wondering why socat can work with this server without any
>   problem?

Probably because socat closes the socket and your client doesn't.

> If so is there a way to let it know how much data it should read
>   without sending the size of data chunk at the beginning of each
>   message?

For instance, reading one byte at a time until you read an end-of-message character, assuming that you're defining / using a protocol that includes EOM.

Comment: You are right, I did not close the socket in my client. Thanks for pointing that out. However this will not fix this problem... The end-of-message is a good solution but I do not know if that can solve this...

Comment: Bi-directionnal communication won't work if the server wait for a fixed number of bytes (2048) while the client writes less. The client has to send at least the number of bytes that the server expect.

Comment: @llya thanks for the hint. I changed my code using `read_some` and detect if reaches the end of input by checking the last character is `\0` or not.